# Trying to Clear All notes when one cell has the checkbox value of true

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to clear all of the notes created in the sheet once the checkbox cell is set to true. It keeps failing. The modification code works perfectly though. Please help.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  // Variables
  const range = e.range;
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var triggercell = sheet.getRange(2, 6).getValue();
  
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());

  // Clears all notes 
  if (triggercell) {
    sheet.clearNote();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ".isChecked()" to get the status of a checkboxes within a Range, this would require some modifications, also, you'll need to use .clearNote***s***() when referring to the whole sheet and not one singular cell:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  // Variables
  const range = e.range;
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var triggercell = sheet.getRange(2, 6); //drop .getValue() in order to make "triggercell" a Range.
  
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());

  // Clears all notes 
  if (triggercell.isChecked()) { //Checking if the Checkbox is checked.
    sheet.clearNotes();
  }
}
```

References:

- [.isChecked() usage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#ischecked)
- [sheet.clearNotes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clearnotes)